# Error including header files in Unreal

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am new to Unreal and I have this project in Unreal. I added a couple of new cpp files which includes some standard header files like string.h, stdlib etc. Intellisense does not give an error but project just won't compile.
This is  the error

`Error  1   error : The first include statement in source file 'C:\<path>\Source\RoboRev_Win\Parser\Parser.cpp' is trying to include the file 'iostream' as the precompiled header, but that file could not be located in any of the module's include search paths. C:\<path>\Intermediate\ProjectFiles\EXEC    RoboRev_Win`

I even tried added paths to include directories under project properties but not use. Can somebody please help ?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem and fixed it by making sure that the common project header was the first include statement on all my files:

If your project name is Foo, make sure that you are not including anything above the line
`#include "Foo.h"`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the standard header files before any `"YourFile.generated.h"` statement.

Also make sure you use the correct syntax, for example

```
#include <regex>
```

instead of

```
#include "regex"
```

If that does not help:

- Maybe post the top of your header file code?
- Are you able to include the files in other c++ projects without error?
- Does your project compile if you do not include these headers?

Comment: I actually solved it by deleting the cpp files and creating them again. It worked second time around. Thanks for the assist though!